# Running MATLAB command that awaits a later command; all in a script

Tags: matlab, tcp, tcpclient, tcpserver, tracker

This is a question to an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22643164/using-matlab-to-open-listening-server-and-client-within-one-script-for-tracking) I had posted it turn out I need to generalize it. So I have these commands:

```
tracker=tcpip('127.0.0.1', 20200, 'NetworkRole', 'server');
fopen(tracker);
system('"C:\PROGRA~1\..." param1 param2')
```

I am using the same computer to be a listening server and a client as communication of an external device to the computer. The issue is the tracker server is waiting for the client to be started (system command).

Any feedback? Thanks

Comment: Why did you start a new question instead of editing the old one?

Comment: Better Views. I feel the old one isn't fresh anymore.

Comment: Please edit the old one in the future if you have information to add.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to do it in a single script. The function `fopen(tracker)` will always wait for a connection. This is because it is supposed that the following instructions will be executed for a client.

Your code is saying: "Wait until a new connection is stablished (`fopen`). Then create a new client (`system`)". This doesn't make sense, so you should execute the client from a different script or program.

You can check it in the Matlab information: http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/instrument/using-tcpip-server-sockets.html

As you can see they specifically say:

> MATLAB Client: This code is running on a second copy of MATLAB.

Comment: Thanks! Wow I have completely  missed that comment. Okay, if run a second copy of Matlab is there still a method to automate the starting of the server and the client.

Comment: So now I am thinking if it's possible to start another session of Matlab with a time delay that will allow the server and the client to start consecutively.

Comment: Are you using Windows or Linux?